# iOS NSJSONSerialization returning null

Tags: ios, json

The App that I'm working on requires to parse a very big Json file (17.5 MB or 17mil characters).

I have coded and tested the App using smaller Json file and was successful doing the parsing, Only when I test using that 17.5 MB file it returns me null object.

I'm using iOS 5.1 and used JSON reader API of iOS 5.0 as well as JSONKIT which both return the same response, NULL.

Any advice would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is a valid (properly formatted) json file?

Comment: Yes I did verify JSON with a simple C# code.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with AFNetworking only that the limit is much lower (around 25kb). If anybody has a solution please send it over.

Thanks

Comment: @Claus I managed to solve this issue by breaking down the file... do so, and I suppose your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is really a size problem you might break it into pieces on some natural boundaries. I have done that with large xml files in the past with good results.

But as @Alladinian mentions in the comments do verify that it is a valid JSON file.

Comment: Yes I did verify JSON with a simple C# code. there is no problem with the JSON file only that I guess the file size is more than what can be cached in the memory. so I'm working on a function to break down the JSON and parse it one by one.

Comment: The fact that another parser accepts it doesn't mean that it's valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, i recently uncovered a bug where NSJSONSerialization fails when the JSON file being parsed is > 32k in size.  when we trimmed the source JSON down, the same code path works just fine.

Comment: Yup mate, Thanks for the info. I did break it into pieces of small JSON file and the problem of memory issue was solved.